# Modifying php.ini setting with chef php cookbook

Tags: php, ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, cookbook

I have installed the PHP Cookbook from opscode and the chef-dotdeb cookbook found at [chef-dotdeb](https://github.com/ffuenf/chef-dotdeb) so that I can run **PHP 5.4** in the vagrant box.

I would like to modify some of the default `php.ini` settings.

According to the documentation for the chef php cookbook I can modify the settings using

```
node['php']['directives'] = {}
```

for example:

```
node['php']['directives'] = { :short_open_tag => 'Off' }
```

I have made the modification in the `webserver.rb` script I have created in my applications cookbook.
When I provision or reload the vagrant box the `php.ini` settings remain unchanged.

Any ideas what is wrong?

The contents of the webserver.rb file are:

include_recipe "nginx"

include_recipe "php"

node.default["php"]["directives"] = { :short_open_tag => 'Off' }

Even when i remove the dotdeb cookbook so that the only php stuff comes from the official opscode php cookbook it still doesnt update any ini values.

ADDITIONAL INFO

I have looked at the code in the opscode php cookbook that actually injects the directives into it erb php.ini template:
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php/blob/master/templates/ubuntu/php.ini.erb

The code that injects the appends the directives to the end of the file is:

```
<% @directives.sort_by { |key, val| key }.each do |directive, value| -%>
<%= "#{directive}=\"#{value}\"" %>
<% end -%>
```

this is always empty {}

However.... if i modify it to...

```
<% node.default[:php][:directives].sort_by { |key, val| key }.each do |directive, value| -%>
<%= "#{directive}=\"#{value}\"" %>
<% end -%>
```

Then the directives ARE injected into the template. Im not a ruby expert. What is the fundamental difference between these 2 pieces of logic???

Comment: Re-provisioning rarely works for me for certain cookbooks.  Have you tried a full `vagrant destroy` and a `vagrant up` explicitly?

Comment: Destroyed the box and then did a vagrant up but still didn't work :(

Comment: My telepathic abilities are somehow limited. Show more code (webserver.rb), how do you call the recipes and the output.

Comment: I use `override_attributes('php'=> { 'conf_dir'=>'/etc/php5/apache2' } )` and it updates the apache configuration instead of the cli... not the cleanest solution but if you only need your webserver config updated that's the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Might be a real long shot but I was trying to use this feature and was finding it doesn't work, then I actually found it's because I was looking at the apache2 php.ini when the cookbook by default only adds the setting to the cli php.ini file. This probably isn't an issue for Fedora/Redhat, but it is for Ubuntu because it separates the configs out under /etc/php5/ into different folders.

Comment: Same issue here. I solved this by just creating a custom template and writing the file with chef template.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue installing priestjims php with Apache. 
Installing Apache first and running apache2::mod_php5 does not mean you can leave out php::apache2 that was the mistake for me.

Solution is to include php::apache2 recipe and then it is writing it's php.ini to 'apache_conf_dir'. This way development ini settings like

```
default['php']['directives'] = {
     'display_errors' => 'On',
     'allow_url_fopen' => 'On',
     'allow_url_include' => 'On',
     'short_open_tag' => 'Off'
}
```

will be correctly applied to apache's php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
node.set['php']['directives'] = { :short_open_tag => 'Off' }
```

And if that doesn't work you can try to use the override option:

```
node.override['php']['directives'] = { :short_open_tag => 'Off' }
```

As of chef 11 you need to set the explicitly set the precedence level:

https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Breaking+Changes+in+Chef+11

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried those and have read that part of the docs. Didn't fix it I'm afraid :(

Comment: when i tried this one this is the generated code
short_open_tag="Off"
but it should be
short_open_tag = Off
and it is only appending on the cli/php.ini not it apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite old question, but it's might help others.

the `@` symbol meant it's a variable. Template resources have variables property and you can add the directives attribute there.

More on the doc:

```
This attribute can also be used to reference a partial template file by using a Hash. For example:

template "/file/name.txt" do
  variables :partials => {
    "partial_name_1.txt.erb" => "message",
    "partial_name_2.txt.erb" => "message",
    "partial_name_3.txt.erb" => "message"
  },
end
where each of the partial template files can then be combined using normal Ruby template patterns within a template file, such as:

<% @partials.each do |partial, message| %>
  Here is <%= partial %>
<%= render partial, :variables => {:message => message} %>
<% end %>
```

https://docs.getchef.com/resource_template.html

If you see the `ini` recipe of cookbook php:

```
template "#{node['php']['conf_dir']}/php.ini" do
    source node['php']['ini']['template']
    cookbook node['php']['ini']['cookbook']
    unless platform?('windows')
        owner 'root'
        group 'root'
        mode '0644'
    end
    variables(:directives => node['php']['directives'])
end
```

https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php/blob/master/recipes/ini.rb

it's assigning the `node['php']['directives']` to variables in template.

Answer (score 0):

Got this this problem that my PHP directives where not applied on PHP running Ubuntu 16.04.
My solution was to override PHP's conf_dir to make the recipe skip cli and update only the config used by Apache2.

```
"override_attributes": {   
      "php": {
            "conf_dir": "/etc/php/7.0/apache2"
```